# jQuery detach div, append div

Tags: jquery, video, append, detach

In Chrome/Safari the Vimeo video continues to play in the background once the the lightbox has been closed. At this point the "detach" works to stop the video but when you close the lightbox and click on a menu item to re-open the video the video div is blank. I've tried "clone" and "append" and can't get the video back in.

Website Function:
Click "a" "b" "c" and the lightbox appears with the video.
Click the "X" in the lightbox the and the lightbox contents close.

```
    HTML/CSS 
    a id="alphaa" <------ The  a, b, c menu item, when clicked, open the lightbox
    .abcbox_content <------- The div that holds all the content for the lightbox
    #videowrapper <------ div that holds the Vimeo iframe
    .abc-align-right <---- the "X" to close the lightbox
```

and here's the jQuery I have so far.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".abc-align-right").click(function() {
    $("#videowrapper").clone(true); 
    $("#videowrapper").contents().detach();
    if ($(".abcbox_content").is(':visible'))
    $("#videowrapper").append();
    }); });
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are cloning the element, but not using the clone. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".abc-align-right").click(function() {

        $("#videowrapper").replaceWith($("#videowrapper").clone(true)); 

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That shows the video but puts the video under the text block, at the very bottom. Maybe referencing the wrong div?

Comment: Maybe. You could try something like `$("#videowrapper").replaceWith($("#videowrapper").clone(true));`

Comment: I don't really know if all that other stuff is needed. Just swap out the elements and call it good. I edited my answer.

Comment: This is only working for video a. I'll have to make divs for the other 2 and add the jquery for those.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Vimeo Javascript API to pause and unpause the video.

See: http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js

You'd have to assign an id to the iframe, and then something like:

```
$(".abc-align-right").click(function() {
  $("#iframe_id").postMessage({ "method": "pause" });
});
```

And whenever you make the lightbox appear call:

```
 $("#iframe_id").postMessage({ "method": "play" });
```

Since you need this to work for 3 videos on the same page you could also use a class for the iframes or separate ids.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but they lost me after adding "api=1" to the url

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I'll give it a shot.